# Python + Appium + Winappdriver + Notepad: self.driver.close_app() doesnt close NotePad

Tags: python, appium, winappdriver

Trying `Python` + `Python Appium Library` + `WinAppDriver` to perform a simple automation task:

1. Launch Notepad
2. Enter some text.
3. Close Notepad without saving

When I close notepad using `self.driver.close_app()` call, it doesn't close it, since there is unsaved text in the notepad window. How can I perform this task without it prompting me to close the Window OR do I need to automate clicking on Don't Save button which will close the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `self.driver.quit()`

OR

Automate the Don't save button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WinAppDriver, but did you try to send it key command for closing Notepad, something like:

```
self.driver.find_element().SendKeys(Keys.Alt + Keys.F4)
```

There is something in here with WinAppDriver that might help if above doesn't https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Tests/WebDriverAPI/SendKeys.cs.